# Setting CURL Arguments in NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, curl, nsurlsession

I am trying to execute the following CURL command in a Mac app in Objective-C:

`curl -u [USERNAME]:[PASSWORD] -X POST --limit-rate 40000 --header "Content-Type: audio/wav” --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @/Users/name/Desktop/test.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"`

I am unsure how to set the various CURL arguments in an NSURLSession. I think I set the HTTP headers correctly, but I don't know how to set the `u`, `limit-rate`, and `data-binary` arguments. This is what I have so far:

```
NSString* credentials = @"[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]";
NSString* audioPath = @"@/Users/name/Desktop/test.wav";
NSString* fullPath = @"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true";
NSURL* fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString: fullPath];

NSURLSessionConfiguration* sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration
                                            defaultSessionConfiguration];
[sessionConfig setHTTPAdditionalHeaders: @{@"Content-Type" : @"audio/wav",
                                           @"Transfer-Encoding": @"chunked"}];

NSMutableData* body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[body appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"u: %@", credentials]
                   dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData: [@"limit-rate: 40000" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData: [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"data-binary: %@", audioPath]
                   dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSession* urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig];
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: fullURL];

[urlRequest setHTTPBody: body];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest
                                               completionHandler: ^(NSData* data,
                                                                    NSURLResponse* response,
                                                                    NSError* error) {
    if (nil == error)
    {
        if (0 != [data length])
        {
            // Do something with the returned JSON
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Data Error: Data is nil or data length is 0.");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

The error I am getting when I run this code is:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Does anybody have any ideas? I think it's not working because I'm setting the CURL arguments incorrectly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: getting same issue did you got any solution?

Comment: @kb920 Unfortunately not yet... I'm still plugging away at it though, so if/when I figure out a solution I'll post here. In the mean time, as a workaround, I've been using NSTask to launch a curl process to do this (which isn't nearly as good, as with that there's a context switch). If you want some help with doing it that way though, I can post that here.

Answer (score 0):

The NSURL family of APIs has no mechanism for rate limiting.  If that's a requirement, you'll have to use libcurl instead.  If not, then:

- The body should be the *contents* of the file (use NSData's dataWithContentsOfURL: method) and nothing else.
- The authentication is too complicated to explain here.

One approach is using the techniques described Apple's [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1), which describes how to do HTTP authentication in depth.

However, the easiest way, by far, to do auth with NSURL* APIs is to just add an Internet password into the keychain, as described in APple's [Keychain Services Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html).